# Remove 'today highlight' from fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar 3.8.2 by FullCalendar LLC and I'm instanciating it like so:

```
$("#calendar-schedules").fullCalendar({
            'themeSystem'   :'bootstrap3',
            'height'        :426
        });
```

I'm trying to remove the highlighting of the current date (not the 'Today' button)

I tried adding the 'now' parameter to false, but then I get error of moment.js saying

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info

How can I achieve such thing?
[image]

Comment: "I get error"...it's not an error it's merely a warning. Basically it's really saying that it can't parse `false` as a Moment, which is not entirely surprising. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/now says you have to provide a momentJS (or moment-parseable) object, or a function for this value. False is not really allowed.

Comment: So what is the best approach to not highlight any date?

Answer (score 5):

You can just change the CSS so that the background colour of the "fc-today" class - which is used on the current date to highlight it - is the same as the default background colour.

Add this CSS somewhere in your page (probably better than overriding it in the fullCalendar CSS file, in case you upgrade the version and forget you made a customisation):

```
.fc-today
{
  background-color:inherit !important;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Lfm1odm1/8/ for a demo.

Answer (score 3):

In V5 of FullCalendar this worked for me.

```
.fc-day-today {
  background-color: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these answered worked for me. What worked was setting the CSS variable:

```
:root {
    --fc-today-bg-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

As seen in [this issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/7150) on their GitHub.

Comment: I think seems like it is most in line with the recommended approach for styling.